# Windows batch script to copy largest file and by pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, pattern-matching

Can anyone tell me how to create a batch file to do the following:

1. Create a folder in the following date format MMDDYYYY
2. Search the current directory for the largest file and copy it into the folder that was created in step 1.
3. Also search the current directory for a second file which matches the largest file which was found and copy it into the directory created in step 1.

> ```
> For example: 
> file1test.txt (3kb) 
> file2test.txt (10 kb)
> file1test.log (2kb) 
> file2test.log (2kb)
> ```

**file2test.txt** is selected and copied into the folder since it is the largest file and **file2test.log** is selected and copied into the same folder as well since it matches the pattern of the largest file.

Comment: *(My numbering is unrelated to yours.)* 1. What particularly have you got difficulties with at this point? 2. Your post actually consists of several problems. If you split it into several questions, you might get better quality answers to each. (The latter would also be beneficial to the community at large.) 3. Would it be correct to assume that by *the pattern* you mean *a file with the same name (and any extension)*? What if there was a file with a so called "double extension", like `file2test.txt.log`? Would it need to match your pattern?

Answer (score 2):

as Andriy already pointed out, there are three questions on your post, and First and Second are already answered in SO.

To solve your latest problem, you need to iterate with `FOR` over the list of files and compare just the part of the filename you want to match.

To help you and get you started, see at the following sample code. I assume from your example that you want to just take the name part, without extension, and I am assuming for this example that the extensions you want are .log and .txt. You will have to complete with the folder part, change and extend it to fit your needs. And, as an added bonus, for this sample to be understendable, I had to solve your second problem too, sorry :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set destfolder=Folder01012001
set largest=
set largestname=
set /a largestsize=0
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
  if %%~za gtr !largestsize! (
    set largest=%%a
    set largestname=%%~na
    set /a largestsize=%%~za
  )
)
set match=
for %%a in (*.log) do (
  if %%~na==!largestname! (
    set match=%%a
  )
)
echo copy "!largest!" %destfolder%
echo copy "!match!" %destfolder%
endlocal
```